# Error: Cannot find module '/home/circleci/project/.circleci/deploy.js' - CircleCI

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

I was trying to deploy my master branch files to FTP server (cpanel, apache) using CircleCI . And I'm following instruction describe [here in this article](https://blog.polarbits.co/2018/01/24/deploy-static-html-website-from-github-repository-to-the-ftp-server-using-circleci/).

But I'm getting error on **"node .circleci/deploy.js"**

Here is the full error log:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail node .circleci/deploy.js internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/circleci/project/.circleci/deploy.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
    at startExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:276:5)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:227:5)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3) Exited with code 1
```

Here is my **config.yml** and config.js file inside ".circleci" folder.

```
version: 2
jobs:
   build:
     docker:
       - image: circleci/node:latest
     steps:
       - checkout
       - run: npm install
       - run: node .circleci/deploy.js
       - run: echo "WE'RE ONLINE"

workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
```

**Config.js file**

```
var FtpDeploy = require('ftp-deploy');
var ftpDeploy = new FtpDeploy();

var config = {
    username: process.env.USERNAME_HV,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD_HV,
    host: process.env.FTPHOST,
    port: 21,
    localRoot: __dirname + "/",
    remoteRoot: "/home/hiversho/public_html/gitlab-pipeline-demo/",
    include: ['*']
}

ftpDeploy.deploy(config, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else console.log('finished');
});
```

In case anyone want to check the entire repo files, [checkout on github](https://github.com/saif71/circleCI_to_ftp_demo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the repo, your file is called .circleci/**config.js**, and you're trying to run .circleci/**deploy.js**

Comment: Thanks for saving my life. I spent two entire night going through hundred of web pages and documentations and of course failed miserably .